# Access 2010 VBA Picture Object in Form

Tags: ms-access

i have a form in access with one field (club_name), i have a picture object in this form. someplace in a folder i have some pictures (*.png) that each club's picture equal to records in my table.for example i have a record "FCB" and in that folder i have a picture "FCB.png". i myself code like this:

> Private Sub Form_Current()
>       Image5.Picture = "C:\Users\Milad\Desktop\club imgs\" & Club_Name.Text & ".png"
>   End Sub

but it's not right.
please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not refer to the text property of controls. It is only avaiable when the control has focus. If you must use a property, use value.

```
Me.Image5.Picture = "C:\Users\Milad\Desktop\club imgs\" & Me.Club_Name & ".png"
```

You can also check that it all works by using a "real" name:

```
Me.Image5.Picture = "C:\Users\Milad\Desktop\club imgs\FCB.png"
```

Re Comment

```
sPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
sBlank = "Blank.png" ''Your own default empty picture

If IsNull(Me.Club_Name) Then
    sFile = sBlank
Else
    ''Does the file exist? Note: Use FilesystemObject
    ''instead if you are working network paths.

    sFile = Dir(sPath & Me.Club_Name & ".png")

    ''Empty string ("")
    If sFile = vbNullString Then
        sFile = sBlank
    End If
End If

Me.Image5.Picture = sPath & sFile
```

Comment: if a picture dosen't match and form go to next ?

Comment: if anybody copy my database folder ( database folder contains Club folder- club folder contain pictures) on his computer, i want to use a function that shom me the databse path like this:  DatabasPath & "\club imgs\" & me.club_name & ".png"

Comment: The database folder is `CurrentProject.Path`. I am not sure what your first comment means?

Comment: i mean that if a picture name doesn't match with field name or a picture doesn't exist, then form show a blank picture.